# 2004 Pontiac Grand Prix ticking under light acceleration

Tags: noise, pontiac, grand-prix

I have a 2004 naturally aspirated grand prix with the 3.8 series 3 3800.
I took out my factory airbox and put in an open cone air filter. Ever since then my car has has a ticking noise while under light acceleration. Theres no noise at idle, or if im over 30% throttle.

Im wondering what are a few possibilities of what could cause this noise?

Comment: Welcome to Motor Vehicle Maintenance & Repair! What exactly is your question?

Comment: What are some possibilities that could cause that?

Comment: The most likely cause is the noise was there all along. The factory airbox is designed to reduce noise coming from the engine. With the cone in place, you now actually hear the noise. More than likely, the noise itself is coming from the lifters/valvetrain ... at least that would be my guess.